# After selecting a few photos from the Photos app on iPhone, can I "LAUNCH" my app and send the selected photos to my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Considering my app has a share extension that shows up on the share extension list when I select a few photos in the photos app, can I "LAUNCH" my app from there and pass the selected assets to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot actually **LAUNCH** your app.

You can launch a view that looks like your app that is actually part of the share extension though, but it doesn't sound like that's what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah. I don't want an in-place view to be shown. I want to launch my application. Thanks Andy!

Comment: Ya kinda frustrating in iOS that you can't do that, as you can in Android

Comment: It's really sad that after all of these years Apple still hasn't updated the Photos app or (the Mail app with image attachments) to allow you to open the images in 3rd party apps. I filed an enhancement request for this a few years ago - still waiting.